# JMS consumers still active after killing Spring app

Tags: jms, spring-jms, activemq-artemis

I have a message processor application that uses a `@JmsListener` method with concurrency `15-15` to read messages from an ActiveMQ Artemis topic.  When the application is running in Linux and I run the `kill` command against that process the 15 consumers slowly start to go away one by one until finally they reach zero after 10 minutes or so.  The process itself stays running until those consumers reach zero.

When I run `kill -9` against that Java process the Java process ends immediately, but still the broker waits for the consumers to slowly die off.

Is there anything special I need to do to clean up all consumers on application shut down?  We need to be able to trust that the `kill` command works immediately and leaves no consumers on the queue.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been caused by using an older version of ActiveMQ Artemis (2.6.3), fixed in 2.8.1

See the ticket here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-2335